# How to acces to an Inner class, which is in an Enum in java

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

i want to know how i can access to a inner class, which is in an Enum.

Example:

```
  public enum myEnum{

    public class myInnerClass{

    public void aMethod(){

    //do somethink.....
    }
    }
    }
```

How can i access to this class(access to it methods) in another class?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Isn't there any `Enum` constant defined within `myEnum`?

Comment: this is the enums name, you can't instantiat an enum

Comment: What do you mean by "access to this class"?

Comment: I mean calling methods of the inner class

Comment: @lisa You don't have any methods in the class, why do you need to *access* them?

Comment: it was just a sample.... i have complete it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the inner class inside the `enum` using it's instance, defined by enum fields:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    INSTANCE_A,
    INSTANCE_B;

    public class MyInnerClass {
        // This is no different from the inner class in a normal class

        public String show() {
            // You can get the name of the instance for which this method was called.
            System.out.println(MyEnum.this.name());
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to create an instance of `MyInnerClass`, you would do:

```
MyEnum instanceA = MyEnum.INSTANCE_A;
MyEnum.MyInnerClass myInnerInstance = instanceA.new MyInnerClass();

System.out.println(myInnerInstance.show());
```

**Output:**

```
INSTANCE_A   // For MyEnum.this.name()
Hello
```

The way is similar to how you would do for an *inner class*, which is inside a normal class. There is no difference.

Comment: Thanks your answer is the best :)

Answer (score 3):

> I mean calling methods of the inner class

To be able to call methods of inner class you'll need an instance of inner class (except for the case when inner class is static and you want to call a static method).

To create an object of innerClass you can do `SSS.INSTANCE.new A();` (class from below)

Or you can declare it `static` then you'll work with it as with normal class.

```
public enum SSS {
INSTANCE;

public static class A {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SSS.A a = new SSS.A();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Class cls = myEnum.myInnerClass.class;
```